# Como fazer uma data especifica do MonthCalendar ficar com fundo vermelho

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou construindo um sistema de reserva de ativos em um projeto Windows Forms. Preciso mostrar aos usuários em quais dias os ativos já foram reservados. Para isso, decidi usar o componente MonthCalendar. Mas esbarrei em um problema: não consigo mudar a cor de uma data específica no MonthCalendar.

Quero destacar os dias reservados para que os usuários possam identificá-los, mas ele não me deixa mudar a cor do fundo, da borda ou seja não me deixa estilizar nada.

Se puderem me ajudar passando alguma biblioteca e como usá-la.

```
 private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
           
            DateTime dataEspecifica = new DateTime(2024, 3, 1);

          
            if (monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date == dataEspecifica)
            {
                
                monthCalendar1.BackColor = Color.Red; 
                monthCalendar1.ForeColor = Color.Red; 
            }
            
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            monthCalendar1.DateChanged += monthCalendar1_DateChanged;
        }
```